# How to acces parent XML element

Tags: xml, groovy

I am iterating an XML file like this:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText(getServiceConfigXml())
            .'**'
            .findAll { it.name() == 'something' }
            .each { node ->

println "attribute: ${node.attributes()} and body: ${node.text()}"
}
```

How can i acces the parent element of 'node' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
${node.parent().attributes()}
```

you can even do

```
${node.parent().parent().attributes()}
```

to access the parent of the parent node